# Python - How would I go about doing this?

Tags: python, function

Here's an example code:

```
def test(something=None):
    test = something is None
    test2 = something is str

    if(test == True):
        return "test = True"

    elif(test2 == True):
        return "test2 = True"

    else:
        return
```

Now, If I ran this and typed in the Python Shell:

```
test()
```

I would get

```
'test = True'
```

But, If I type:

```
test("This is a string")
```

I do not get returned "test2 = True" which Is what I want, I simply get returned nothing.

I know why this happens but how would I go about doing it correctly and make it so when I type in the Python Shell:

```
test("String")
```

or any other string, I would get returned "test2 = True" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string object is not identical to the `str` type object. It is an *instance* of that type, not the type itself.

You could use the [`type()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) to test for the types of objects:

```
>>> type('this is a string') is str
True
```

but you generally want to use the [`isinstance()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) instead:

```
>>> isinstance('this is a string', str)
True
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I do isinstance for None ? I tried isinstance(None,None) and got a NameError error

Comment: @BlaZe: Just use `is None` for that test, or use `isinstance(object, type(None))`, but the latter is not very pythonic..